# 5 distinct number distributed to 5 persons

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

$5$ distinct numbers are randomly distributed to players numbered $1$ to $5$. Whenever two players compare their numbers, the one with the higher one is the winner. Initially, players 1 and 2 compare their numbers; the winner then compares with player 3 and so on. Let $X$ denote the number of times player 1 is a winner. Find  $P(X=i),i∈(0,1,2,3,4)$

I know $P(0)=1/2$ because since the numbers are random player 1 has an equal probability of beating player 2 but after that im kind of cunfused on how to proceed.

Any tips to point me in the right direction would help me alot.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I take P(i) to mean wins *at least* i games, we get player 1 must draw on of the top n-i cards and players 2 - n+1 must draw lower cards.

P(0) = 5/5 = 1.

P(1) = highest card 1/5*4/4 + 2nd highest 1/5*3/4 + 1/5*2/4 + 1/5*1/4 = 1/5*1/4(4 + 3 + 2 + 1) = 1/2.

P(2) = 1/5*4/4*3/3 + 1/5*3/4*2/3 + 1/5*2/4*1/3 = 1/5*1/12(12 + 6 + 2) = 1/3

P(3) = 1/5*4/4*3/3*2/2 + 1/5*3/4*2/3*1/2 = 1/5*1/24(24 + 6) = 1/4

P(4) = 1/5*4/4*3/3*2/2*1/1 = 1/5.

Cute, huh?

But maybe we were supposed to take P(i) meaning player 1 won *exactly* i games.  *sigh*

To win 0 games. Player 1 can draw the lowest card (1/5) and player 2 play any other card (4 out 4 remaining).  The 2nd lowest card (1/5) and player w draw any card higher (3/4 3 of the 4 remaining) The 3rd lowest card and player w and card higher (2/4 2 of the 4 remaining) etc.

That is P(0) = 1/5*4/4 + 1/5*3/4 + 1/5*2/4 + 1/5*1/4 + 1/5*0/4 = 1/5*1/4(4 + 3 + 2 + 1) = 1/2.

To win 1 game. Player 1 can't draw the lowest card .Player 1 can draw the second lowest card and player 2 the lowest and player 3 any of the 3 higher cards, or player 1 the 2nd lowest card, player 1 one of the 2 remaining and player 3 onle of the 2 higher cards, or....

Then P(1) =  1/5*(1/4)*3/3 + 1/5*(2/4)*2/3 + 1/5*(3/4)*1/3  = 1/5[ 3/12 + 4/12 + 3/12  ] = 1/6.

P(2) =  1/5(2/4*1/3)2/2 + 1/5(3/4*2/3)1/2  = 1/5*1/24[ 4 + 6] = 1/12

p(3) = 1/5*(3/4*2/3*1/2)*1/1 = 1/20

p(4) = 1/5*(4/4*3/3*2/2*1/1) = 1/5

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Player $1$ wins at least once if their number is highest out of the first two, with probability (what?).  They win at least twice if their number is highest out of the first three, with probability (what?).  They win at least three times if $\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Just count favorable permutations of the concerned **blocks** in sequences

$P(0) = \dfrac{1}{2!} = \dfrac12\;\; [ .... 21 .... ]$

$P(1) = \dfrac1{3!} = \dfrac1{6}\;\; [ .... 312 .... ]$

$P(2) = \dfrac{2!}{4!} = \dfrac1{12}\;\; [ ....4123, 4132,.... ]$, and so on

$P(3) = \dfrac{3!}{5!} = \dfrac{1}{20}$

$P(4) = \dfrac{4!}{5!} = \dfrac15$